# getUserMedia in Firefox in Docker not working when using audio

Tags: selenium, firefox, docker, webrtc, getusermedia

I am experiencing a weird behaviour of the WebRTC's `getUserMedia` function when using Firefox 52+ in Docker. The steps to reproduce it are:

1) Run a Selenium Hub in Docker:

```
docker run --rm --name selenium-hub -p 4444:4444 selenium/hub:3.4.0
```

2) Register a Firefox browser in the hub:

```
docker run --rm --link selenium-hub:hub -p 5555:5555 -p 5900:5900 selenium/node-firefox-debug:3.4.0
```

*NOTE 1*: This command is using the debug version of the node-firefox image since we want to connect to the browser (in the container) using VNC

*NOTE 2*: This version (3.4.0) is using Firefox 53. This problem also happens since Firefox 52 (i.e. 52, 53, 54), but the problem does not happen in Firefox 51 (node-firefox-debug:3.1.0)

3) Connect to the browser using a VNC client (URL in Linux: vnc://127.0.0.1:5900, password: secret)

4) Force to use fake media in the dockerized browsers. This can be done setting to `true` the configuration key `media.navigator.streams.fake` in the advance configuration of Firefox (tab `about:config`):

[image]

5) Open the [getUserMedia samples page](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/) in Firefox in Docker. For instance, the [Basic getUserMedia demo](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/) works fine:

[image]

I checked this demo is working because the in the `mediaConstraints` the **audio flag is set to false**:

```
var constraints = window.constraints = {
  audio: false,
  video: true
};
```

Nevertheless, any other demo which sets the audio flag to true is not going to work, and the `getUserMedia` function get stalled.

The strange thing is this behaviour can only be reproduced in Docker, i.e., any version of Firefox running directly in a host works fine. It seems there is some kind of bug here, but I am not sure in which part of the puzzle.

Where is the problem here? Docker? Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same problem running adapter.js on travis-ci. The solution is shown [in this pull request](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/pull/504) -- you need to start pulseaudio